# What's the cost of upgrading cabins at Tallink Silja during cruise?

Tags: cruising, upgrades, tallink-silja

During cruise trips with Tallink Silja I've many times wanted to upgrade my cabin to a larger one, one without engine noise and sometimes a suite.

What's the price when doing it during a cruise?

Will it be cheaper than buying a ticket for that cabin in the harbor terminal or [upgrading before departure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/153512/18374)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: You can "upgrade" during a cruise.

---

There's no such thing as upgrading during a cruise with Tallink Silja. But what you can do is to get another cabin and surrender the keys to your old cabin (if you want). The result is the same as for an upgrade.

The **prices** are fixed and are full-price with no option of getting it cheaper or paying with membership points. For example the suite from Turku to Stockholm (one way) will set you back around 500€ while you can get it both ways for just 40€ as a member when using points.

---

*If you just want to get rid of your snoring room mate there are free earplugs offered at the information desk.*

Comment: Now I want to know how to use ear plugs to get rid of a room mate, but that would be a particularly gory crime novel ;)