# Can you change cabin with Tallink Silja before departure?

Tags: bookings, cruising, tallink-silja

Can I upgrade or downgrade my cabin with Tallink Silja before departure? Say I booked a cabin for two and now two more friends want to join, can I change to a premium cabin for four? Or will the other two friends have to make a new reservation?

Comment: Do the extra passengers already have a ticket without a cabin booking, or do they currently have no ticket at all?

Comment: @gerrit they could obviously join in the cabin already if they were allowed to board.

Comment: Only if you can upgrade from a two-person to a four-person cabin first, unless you want to squeeze four people into a two-person cabin, which you probably don't want and which might not be allowed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you manage to convince the customer service agent to do it for you (it helps if you're a regular). I've done it a few times. You'll want to arrive at the terminal some 40-60 minutes before arrival to be sure that you have enough time to do it. Note that the price usually gets higher the later you book.

If you want to upgrade your cabin *after* departure (on board) you'll have to pay full price for the cabin according to a price list (around 300 EUR for a suite). You get to keep the other cabin.

Getting extra keys for your cabins is possible, both before departure and after, since the price you pay is for the cabin and not per person. If the new keyholders want to collect points then you must do it in the terminal, before departure.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Daniils answer: while on board, you can always contact the customer service desk.  Even if cabins are shown as sold out prior to departure, there may always be some no-shows, and after departure, they may be willing to upgrade you.  When we took the ferry from Savona to Barcelona, cabins were sold out at booking time, but we still managed to upgrade to one after the ferry had departed.  This is at the discretion of the crew and it never hurts to ask, even if the possibility is not spelt out online or the website shows cabins as fully booked.

Comment: I am not sure that will work if the original cabin is for a smaller number of passengers than now want to occupy it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It's never sure whether it will work, but if the new cabin is available and traveller pays the full price for it, I don't see why not.

Comment: The problem I would expect would be getting the extra passengers onto the ship, not with upgrading among cabins large enough for all the passengers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Oh, I was interpreting the extra passengers were already on the ship, but on a ticket without a cabin booking (deck passage, pullman seat / reclining chair, or similar).  Asked OP to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

According to their [Terms and Conditions](https://www.tallinksilja.com/travel-terms-and-conditions-for-individuals):

> **3. TICKET CHANGING**
>
> (1) It is allowed to change the direction and/or itinerary set on the ticket, the date or time of departure, **cabin class**, vehicle and on-board service, and any changes to the above-mentioned services may change the fare to be paid.

If you scroll down on that page there are specific time frames in which you can change your ticket depending on the ferry route.

To add passengers you might need [contact them](https://www.tallinksilja.com/travel-terms-and-conditions-for-individuals):

> Email: **international.sales@tallinksilja.com**
>
> Phone number: **+49(0)40 547 541 222**

Comment: Can you make the changes in the terminal too?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder depending on the route, what is your route?

Comment: is there any terminal where you can't do it?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Ticket changing on the Tallinn - Helsinki route is not possible 45 min before departure. For all other terminals: The passenger cannot change the direction and/or itinerary, the date and time of departure or the number of passengers less than 24 hours before departure.

Comment: Same here, in practise you can change anything at the terminal until the winute the gate closes.